# Operation of Filter Methode

Tags: python, list, function

why is the answer a empty List with `list` command?

```
myList = [12,15,10,16,20]
even_numbers = lambda value: value%2==0
repo = filter(even_numbers,myList)
for x in repo:
    print(x)
list(repo)
```

I want to  clear the problem in my code

Answer (score 1):

Because `filter` returns a generator, not a list.  The `for` loop consumes everything in the generator, leaving it empty.  If you need to reuse the contents, convert it to a list:

```
repo = list(filter(even_numbers,myList))
```

or use a comprehension:

```
repo = [e for e in myList if even_numbers(e)]
```